# find hidden controls on winform and make them visible on runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

i have this situation, i have a winform which has arround 10 to 15 lable and comboboxes which are all not visible. now at runtime i am passing a how many to of these to be activated? their name properties are from lable1 to lable16 and combobox1 to combobox16. i am using the following code only to test if i can find the controls but it seems to fail all, ho and by the was these controls and comboboxes are over a pannel.

the following is the code i used:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls) 
            { 
                if (ctrl is Label) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(((Label)ctrl).Text); 
                } 
          }
```

Comment: in your `else`, call this method recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually sort of answered your own question...
You don't find the controls in `this.Control`s but `Panel1.Controls` :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to replace `this.Controls` with `this.Panel1.Controls` or what ever your panel control name is.

Also mayne rather have a look at [Control.ControlCollection.Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  to make use of the control name.

Answer (score 2):

**You have to make this recursive.**

The `ctrl` itself also has a `Controls`. If you just walk the entire tree, you will eventually find all controls.

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether the current control (ctrl) has controls or not in order to loop through them

e.g.:

```
if (ctrl.Controls.Count >0)
{
//do your logic here
}
```